# Listview is not upadating after return from stand by

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

In my application i uses a thread to receive data and updates the listview in main activity.  It works fine.  But the phone goes sleep.  After returning from sleep the listview in the main activity clears and data is not updated in listview.  Refer following code

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DeviceDiscovery.Listener {
    private static final String TAG = "Main Activity";
    static DeviceDiscovery mDeviceDiscovery = new DeviceDiscovery();
    ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDevices);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(!mDeviceDiscovery.isAlive()){
            mDeviceDiscovery.setListener(this);
            mDeviceDiscovery.start();
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeviceDiscovery(final OV788DiscoveryPacket discoveryPacket,
            final InetAddress IPAddress, final int Port) {
        try {
            String s;
            s =   " Camera Name : " +  discoveryPacket.CameraName + "\n";
            s +=  " Model Number : " +  discoveryPacket.ModelNumber + "\n";
            s +=  " Product Ver : " + discoveryPacket.ProductVersion + "\n";
            Log.d(TAG, "" + s);
            adapter.add(s);
        } catch( Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: where are you initializing values ?

Comment: Values are shown log but not updating in listview after return from sleep

Comment: I mean where are you initializing the ArrayList `values`

Comment: where is data in values. values are empty and you pass them to ArrayAdapter. Try my Answer below.

Comment: @A.Wali I want to update the values received from thread.  So not initially added value to arraylist value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should do this....Try and reply back if it works.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DeviceDiscovery.Listener {
private static final String TAG = "Main Activity";
static DeviceDiscovery mDeviceDiscovery = new DeviceDiscovery();
ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 if(!mDeviceDiscovery.isAlive()){
        mDeviceDiscovery.setListener(this);
        mDeviceDiscovery.start();
    }      

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDevices);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
@Override
public void onDeviceDiscovery(final OV788DiscoveryPacket discoveryPacket,
        final InetAddress IPAddress, final int Port) {
    try {
        String s;
        s =   " Camera Name : " +  discoveryPacket.CameraName + "\n";
        s +=  " Model Number : " +  discoveryPacket.ModelNumber + "\n";
        s +=  " Product Ver : " + discoveryPacket.ProductVersion + "\n";
        Log.d(TAG, "" + s);
        values.add(s);
    } catch( Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't tell what is causing the data to clear from the given piece of code but you can try updating the list in `onResume`

Somthing like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code and Not updating values after sleep

Answer (score 0):

In your onDeviceDiscovery() method, add "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();" after "values.add(s)".

The listview adapter should always be notified of data changes.

Comment: To avoid two methods (values.add(s) & adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();) i used a single method **adapter.add(s)** to update.  See my question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have not shown or you have not initialized the `ArrayList<String> values` .

Then after you have initialized the ArrayList . and when you want to update the listview you have to use the method [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) .

in your case you have to use it like this-

```
.......
s +=  " Product Ver : " + discoveryPacket.ProductVersion + "\n";
        Log.d(TAG, "" + s);
        adapter.add(s);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //this will notify the listview that the data set is changed and will be updated in the listview.
    } catch( Exception e ){
.......
```